How to add a simple ASTextNode(UILabel) to a ASDKViewController(UIViewController)?
I am learning AsyncDisplayKit(Texture), and I am learning how to layout things, I want to add a simple ASTexNode(UILabel) to ASDKViewController(UIViewController) and the text node is showing up please find the code below.
This is basic TextVC class
import AsyncDisplayKit

class TextVC: ASDKViewController<BaseNode> {
    
    let textNode = ASTextNode()
    
    override init() {
        super.init(node: BaseNode())
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        textNode.automaticallyManagesSubnodes = true
        textNode.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        textNode.maximumNumberOfLines = 1
        textNode.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: "This is a sample string",
                                                     attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white,
                                                                  NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 25)])
        node.addSubnode(textNode)
        node.layoutSpecBlock = { [unowned self] node, constrainedSize in
            return ASWrapperLayoutSpec(layoutElement: textNode)
        }
//        node.layoutSpecBlock = { [unowned self] node, constrainedSize in
//            return ASCenterLayoutSpec(centeringOptions: ASCenterLayoutSpecCenteringOptions.XY, sizingOptions: ASCenterLayoutSpecSizingOptions.minimumXY, child: textNode)
//        }
    }
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        print(String(describing: TextVC.self) + " viewWillAppear called")
    }
    
}

This is BaseNode
import AsyncDisplayKit

class BaseNode: ASDisplayNode {
    
    override init() {
        super.init()
        self.automaticallyManagesSubnodes = true
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    }
    
}

The text node is not showing up on the screen.
